# ambiguity regarding Java's import syntax

Tags: java, package, ambiguity

while preparing for the JCA exam I just came across this snippet

```
import java.lang.String.*; 
class EJava 
{
String guru; 
}
```

This is of course nonsense code as java.lang is imported by default. Anyway, the author wants to use it to make the point that this code won't compile as it uses an incorrect import syntax.

The code does compile, though. So is it just the case that an import using a wildcard can simply mean two things?

```
import somepackage.*; // import any type in the package somepackage 

import somepackage.type.*; // import any member of this type (equivalent to : import somepackege.type;)
```

Comment: To import any member you need import static?

Answer (score 4):

This would definitely compile, but the statement will import all **public nested classes** in the `java.lang.String` class and unfortunately there are none.

So effectively the statement is useless yet harmless. There should be no problem in compilation.

---

If you were using static import, the case would have been different, as there are many static methods in `String` class.

Comment: @AndrewTobey The classes are already public and visible. It would just save you writing the full qualified name of the nested class. Also, it doesn't include the import of the class itself, only its public nested classes.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic for replacing inner with nested. I had missed that case. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)

> A *type-import-on-demand* declaration allows all accessible types of a
>   named package or type to be imported as needed.
>
> [...]
>
> A *static-import-on-demand* declaration allows all accessible static
>   members of a named type to be imported as needed.

So your

```
import java.lang.String.*;
```

would import all accessible **types** in `String` (there are no accessible ones in Oracle JDK 8). A `static` import would import all accessible `static` members, **including methods**.